# Will horizontalAccuracy of CLLocation have value infinity in some cases?

Tags: ios, core-location, moya

I am currently working on a crash issue reported by a customer. From the crash logs seems like our app is trying to send location data to backend in JSON format, and it throws
`Invalid number value (infinite) in JSON write` because JSON does not support infinity value.

The app uses Moya library to send data, and here's the location data being sent (where location variable is of type `CLLocation` returned by iOS location update):

```swift
var dict =  ["latitude": location.coordinate.latitude,
                     "longitude": location.coordinate.longitude,
                     "speed": location.speed >= 0 ? location.speed : 0,
                     "altitude": location.altitude,
                     "horizontal_accuracy_estimate": location.horizontalAccuracy,
                     "vertical_accuracy_estimate": location.verticalAccuracy] as [String: Any]
```

So I'm guessing one of the parameters here has the value `Double.infinity`

However, upon checking the Apple documentation, it does not specify or even mention infinity being one of the possible values so I am confused.

I am guessing `horizontalAccuracy` might be `Double.infinity` when the location is really inaccurate? But in that case wouldn't it be better not to return it at all? Because in our app we set:

```
desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
```